# merged pcap file from mergecap command

Tags: merge, pcap

I have created a merge script to merge all pcap files in a folder to a single file. Merge function works. But is there any way to test if the contents of the merged file and the input files are same? Because the application which I have to read through the file says, merged file is corrupt some how.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load the merged file with wireshark or tcpdump which should tell you if it is corrupt. But maybe the file is not corrupt, but in a format your application does not understand. Try to merge with output format 'pcap', e.g. `mergecap -F pcap`, because some application do not work with pcapng (used by wireshark).

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes with `mergecap` and `tcpslice`. They don't work well if the input pcap files aren't perfect.

This can be solved using `joincap`.

```
go get -u github.com/assafmo/joincap
```

To merge `1.pcap` and `2.pcap`:

```
joincap 1.pcap 2.pcap > merged.pcap
```

I wrote `joincap` to overcome what I believe is bad error handling by `mergecap` and `tcpslice`.
For more details go to https://github.com/assafmo/joincap.